# Automatically update preferredContentSize upon rotation

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, ios-app-extension

I am looking for a way to enforce a `UIPopoverPresentationController` automatically resize to fill most of the screen, minus say 50 units of padding.

I first tried settings the `preferredContentSize` in `viewDidLoad`, and then detect when rotation occurs and update that `CGSize` to the new size I could calculate. But for some reason, this isn't working in my context. I was using `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` which normally calls the method, but it's not called when the popover exists within a photo editing extension.

I am wondering if there's any other way to change the popover size besides manually updating the `preferredContentSize` after detecting a size change? If not, is there a way to detect rotation from within this popover in this context?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
func isLandscape() -> Bool {
// your logical here
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        let myNewSize = isLandscape() ? mySizeLandscape : mySizePortrait
        self.preferredContentSize = myNewSize
        super.viewWillTransition(to: myNewSize, with: coordinator)
}
```